# Stream Data to Website from Android device

Tags: android, node.js, stream

For a project I would like to stream the sensor data of an Accelerometer (from an android phone) to a website.

Basically I have written the application that reads the data and stores it on the phone and converts it to a string. I just want to plot the x, y and z Values as line graph dynamically on a website. So If I shake my phone, the line on the website should be moving.

I had several ideas like using Node.js or Java webserver but I couldn't found any appropriate tutorials.
So maybe someone got a good idea where to find tutorials, where I can learn how to stream data to a website from my phone. It should be easy to do or not that hard but I am not very good in making webservers or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep sending your data to the server ideally making post request.

Your webserver can just read the data from the obtained requests and update the graph.

How to write a server ? go through the below link
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/singlethreaded-server.html
how to post data from android ? use an async task doing the below things

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.server.com/");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("graphvalue", "12345"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much for that tutorial atm it's already really helpful ^^... Anyway I am not really good at server making and it's not totally clear for me atm. 
I mean I can use ofc Java but also NodeJS maybe thats easier? The aim is to see the graph online from any device. So I get webspace from my university and need to host there my server or website. 
I just want to lets for example enter "www.accelerometer.com" and see the graph moving if I shake my phone.

Comment: The most important is that the data has to be real time you know... I mean if i shake the phone in the best way the curve should move too ^^...
If it's possible ofc... Anyway I would be happy to get that to a website already.